# Stripe.js payment does not work for some customers only

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments, laravel-7

I have a php (Laravel 7) website that uses Stripe.js to accept credit card payments. The integration usually works nicely, but from time to time, I have some customers, who are not able to make a payment. There is no error message, all I know from the customers is something like this:

"I entered the card details, clicked "Pay" and then a white field and nothing..."

On the stripe backend, I see the payment with status payment "Incomplete" and the "Customer has not entered its payment method". I believe this means that the customer came to the payment page, but has not (could not?) finished the payment for some reason.

Please see some code excerpts below. The first code shows how I create a payment intent when the payment page is loaded. The second one shows the payment form and js code to make the payment. My suspicion is that somehow the js code breaks down for some customers...

Any ideas why this is not working for some customers or how I could debug the root-cause?

Thanks,
W.

---

GNGBookingController.php:

```
function show_step4($id){

            // Create and send payment intent
            \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));
            $idstr =  '[T#' . sprintf('%04d', $tour->id) . ']';

            try{

                $intent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
                    'amount' => round($tour->fees->plat_fee * 100),
                    'currency' => 'eur',
                    'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
                    'description' => $idstr, 
                    ]);

            }
            catch(\Exception $e) {

                GNGLogger::qlog('Failed to create payment intent. ' . $e->getFile() . ' ' .  $e->getLine() . $e->getMessage(), GNGLogType::Error);
                redirect(route('office.' . app::getLocale() . '.crash.show'));
            }

            return view('backoffice.booking.ver2.show-step4', [
                'tour' => $tour, 
                'clientSecret' => $intent->client_secret, 
                'date' => $date, 
                'time' => $time, 
            ]);
}
```

show-step4.blade.php:

```
@extends('backoffice.layouts.guest')
    
@section('content')

<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-2 col-lg-3 col-xl-4">
      
  </div>

  <div class="col">
      <h3>{{__('Advance Payment')}}</h3>

      <form id="payment-form" method="post" data-secret="{{$clientSecret}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="token" />
        <div id="payment-form-holder" class="my-4 p-3 border rounded shadow" style="background-color: lightgrey">
        @csrf

        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="ID" id="ID" value="{{$tour->id}}">
        </div>

       <div class="form-group">
          <label>{{__('Card Number')}}</label><br>
          <div id="card-number">
          </div>
       </div>

       <div class="form-row">
          <div class='col'>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>{{__('Expiry Date')}}</label><br>
                <div id="card-expiry">
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class='col'>
            <label>{{__('Security Code')}}</label><br>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div id="card-cvc">
              </div>
            </div>   
          </div>
       </div>

        <!-- We'll put the error messages in this element -->
        <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
        <div class="form-row my-3" style="flex-wrap: nowrap">
            <div class="spinner-border text-danger" id="spinner" role="status" style="display: none;">
            </div>
            <div id="spinner-text" class="mx-2" style="display: none;">
            {{__('Please wait. This can take up to a minute...')}}
            </div>
        </div>

        <p id="card-error" role="alert"></p>
        <p id="result-message" class="result-message" style="display: none;">
        {{__('Payment succeeded!')}}  
        </p>

        <div class="form-row">
          <input type="submit" id="pay" name="pay" class="btn btn-primary gng-action-button mr-3 mb-3" style="min-width: 100%" value="{{__('Pay :platFee €', ['platFee' => $tour->fees->plat_fee])}}" >
        </div>

      </div>
      
      <input type="submit" id="back" name="back" class="btn btn-secondary gng-action-button mr-3 mb-3" value="{{__('Back')}}" >
      </form>
    
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-2 col-lg-3 col-xl-4">
      
  </div>

</div>

@endsection

@section('scripts')

<script>

// Create a Stripe client
var stripe = Stripe('{{env('STRIPE_KEY')}}');

// Set up Stripe.js and Elements to use in checkout form
var elements = stripe.elements();
var style = {
  base: {
    color: "#32325d",
    fontSize: "18px",
  }
};

var classes = {
    base: 'form-control', 
  };



var cardNumberElement = elements.create('cardNumber', {
  style: style, 
  classes: classes, 
});
cardNumberElement.mount('#card-number');

var cardExpiryElement = elements.create('cardExpiry', {
  style: style, 
  classes: classes,
});
cardExpiryElement.mount('#card-expiry');

var cardCvcElement = elements.create('cardCvc', {
  style: style, 
  classes: classes,
});
cardCvcElement.mount('#card-cvc');

document.querySelector('#payment-form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {

  if (e.submitter.name == 'pay') {

    e.preventDefault();
    loading(true);
    stripe
      .confirmCardPayment('{{$clientSecret}}', {
        payment_method: {
          card: cardNumberElement, 
          billing_details: {
          name: '{{$tour->guest->name}}'
          }
        }
      })
      .then(function(result) {
        if (result.error) {
          // Show error to your customer
          showError(result.error.message);
        } else {
          // The payment succeeded!
          orderComplete(result.paymentIntent.id);
          stripe.createToken(cardNumberElement, options).then(submitToken);
        }
      });

    var options = {
      //address_zip: document.getElementById('postal-code').value,
    };
     
  }

});

function submitToken(result) {

    var form = document.querySelector('#payment-form');
    form.querySelector('input[name="token"]').setAttribute('value', result.token.id);
    form.submit();

}

/* ------- UI helpers ------- */
// Shows a success message when the payment is complete
var orderComplete = function(paymentIntentId) {
  loading(false);
  document.querySelector(".result-message").style.display = 'flex';
  document.querySelector("#pay").disabled = true;
  document.querySelector("#back").disabled = true;
};

// Show the customer the error from Stripe if their card fails to charge
var showError = function(errorMsgText) {
  loading(false);
  var errorMsg = document.querySelector("#card-error");
  errorMsg.textContent = errorMsgText;
  setTimeout(function() {
    errorMsg.textContent = "";
  }, 4000);
};

// Show a spinner on payment submission
var loading = function(isLoading) {
  if (isLoading) {
    // Disable the button and show a spinner
    document.querySelector("#pay").disabled = true;
    document.querySelector("#back").disabled = true;
    document.querySelector("#spinner").style.display = 'flex';
    document.querySelector("#spinner-text").style.display = 'flex';
    document.querySelector("#pay").style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector("#back").style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    document.querySelector("#pay").disabled = false;
    document.querySelector("#back").disabled = false;
    document.querySelector("#spinner").style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector("#spinner-text").style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector("#pay").style.display = 'inline-block';
    document.querySelector("#back").style.display = 'inline-block';
  }
};

</script>

@endsection
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is only breaking for some customers, I suspect this is a device/browser compatibility issue. Whenever this happens, be sure to ask what device and browser they are using when submitting payment. Then, you can verify if they are using a [stripe.js compatible browser](https://stripe.com/docs/js/appendix/supported_browsers). If they are using a stripe.js compatible browser, my recommendation is to install whatever browser they are using and test your flow (while inspecting the developer console for errors).